# Symfony RestBundle with JMSSerialization setSerializationContext

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

in `"friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "~1.4",` we have setSerializationContext from `"jms/serializer-bundle": "^1.1.0",` in this context we set gropu and enable depth

```
        return View::create()
        ->setStatusCode(200)
        ->setData($certificatesResponse)
        ->setSerializationContext(
            SerializationContext::create()
                ->enableMaxDepthChecks()
                ->setGroups(array('certificates_by_parameters'))
        );
```

early in `"friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "~1.4",` we have this function for View class from RestBundle

```
    /**
 * Sets the serialization context.
 *
 * @param SerializationContext $serializationContext
 *
 * @return View
 */
public function setSerializationContext(SerializationContext $serializationContext)
{
    $this->serializationContext = $serializationContext;

    return $this;
}
```

In `"friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.0",` I don't find this function, how to set serialized context in 2.0 version ?

Comment: You should for `setSerializationContext` here https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/UPGRADING-2.0.md

Answer (score 5):

You should look here https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/UPGRADING-2.0.md.

==>

`View::setSerializationContext and View::getSerializationContext have been removed. Use View::setContext and View::getContext together with the new Context class instead.`

`Before:`

```
use JMS\Serializer\SerializationContext;

$view = new View();

$context = new SerializationContext();
$view->setSerializationContext($context);

$context = $view->getSerializationContext();
```

`After:`

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Context\Context;

$view = new View();

$context = new Context();
$view->setContext($context);

$context = $view->getContext();
```